# Remove blank row while pasting data from Excel to Angular Kendo UI grid

Tags: excel, angular, angular-directive, linefeed

I am using the following example:
[excel-paste](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/how-to/paste-from-excel/)

Please look at the `excel-paste.directive.ts`
Once the data is pasted, I need to validate and save data to database. When I paste data from Excel to the grid, in the directive it uses line feed to split and adds an extra blank row at the bottom. I tried replacing line feed with carriage return using '\r\n', but that does the same.

```
const rows = data.split('\n');
```

Please guide if there is a way to remove that empty line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) function, to remove the last element of the array.

```
const rows = data.split('\n');
rows.pop();
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do it all in one line you could use the [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function to copy all elements except for the last from the array.

```
const rows = data.split('\n').slice(0, -1);
```